# Django Zinnia blog error for entries

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fix issue with Zinnia blog application and its popping up error related to aggregator and entries. Following is the code if someone have a suggestion:

```
def get_authors(context, template='zinnia/tags/authors.html'):
    """
    Return the published authors.
    """

    return {'template': template,
            'authors': Author.published.all().annotate(
                count_entries_published=Count('entries')),
            'context_author': context.get('author')}
```

Above I don't think causing any issue but below is the code that might be causing all the fuss in second last line.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return a queryset containing published entries.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        return super(
            EntryRelatedPublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            models.Q(entries__start_publication__lte=now) |
            models.Q(entries__start_publication=None),
            models.Q(entries__end_publication__gt=now) |
            models.Q(entries__end_publication=None),
            entries__status=PUBLISHED,
            entries__sites=Site.objects.get_current()
            ).distinct()
```

Please suggest a solution because overall Zinnia is an impressive app but with one error its almost useless. Owner of the repo already got plenty of users with same complain. Error is same with both Python2 and PYthon3.

For generous coders willing to work on this, repo is located at https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues.

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\template\library.py" in render
  225.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django_blog_zinnia-0.18-py2.7.egg\zinnia\templatetags\zinnia.py" in get_authors
  85.             'authors': Author.published.all().annotate(

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\manager.py" in all
  160.         return self.get_queryset()

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django_blog_zinnia-0.18-py2.7.egg\zinnia\managers.py" in get_queryset
  107.             entries__sites=Site.objects.get_current()

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1247.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1133.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1019.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

File "C:\Users\Shazia\zinblog\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1327.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /weblog/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'entries' into field. Choices are: comment_comments, comment_flags, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
```

Comment: `Count('entries')` shouldn't be `Count(entries)` in `get_authors(**)`?

Comment: Entries is a string. So that's correct presentation.

Comment: And why do you retrieve all other entities `entries = Entry.objects.all()`, because you never use them in that context.

Comment: I tried to use it but that didn't worked either. M going to remove it.

Comment: Removed. So know all we have is the code from original repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try registering django_comments after zinnia in the INSTALLED_APPS setting not before.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'mptt',
  'tagging',
  'zinnia',
  'django_comments',
)
```

Got this solution from the owner of repo. Check the issue on Github.

Comment: Thank you so much...it took me couple of days on this issue.